# How to send data which increases after the base64 encoding?

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, developer

I'm trying to send an attachment through api call, my file size is 4.5mb which increases to more than 6mb after base 64 encoding. and it start throwing error of 6 mb limit which salesforce support for api. Is there any way that I can send data of same size.I mean any encoding which will not increase the size or by any way blob value we can send.

Comment: For which API? There may be an alternative, but we won't know without knowing more details.

Comment: Through REST API I'm trying to send. We have a rest resource class in salesforce which handle the request but ends up throwing error 6 mb limit @sfdcfox

Comment: This may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you trying to accomplish by uploading these files? Apex is going to be limited, but you might be able to use a different technique to arrive at a solution. Please [edit] your question to include as many details as possible, and we'll be glad to try and help.